# IntelliJ is not detecting php.ini inside a container when using docker compose

Tags: docker, intellij-idea, docker-compose, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm trying to configure Xdebug for IntelliJ and my docker-compose project. Xdebug is installed and loaded inside the app container, I have confirmed this with `phpinfo();` , the `php.ini` file that is responsible for the configuration of Xdebug is also loaded which was confirmed through `php --ini`.

**The problem.** IntelliJ detects my container from which it can determine a PHP version as well as a host of other configuration files. But `php.ini` is not detected and Xdebug is not detected, I confirmed this through the phpinfo output that IntelliJ provides.

Any help would be much appreciated.

edit: I don't have any other containers running, only `web` and `db`. IntelliJ is targeting `web` for its scan.

Comment: Is the PHP version successfully detected for the remote interpreter?

Comment: Yes, the version detected is identical to what is running in the container.

Comment: Hard to say then. Unless `php` and what you specified in `PHP interpreter path` are two different interpreters, PhpStorm should be able to read the .ini files. You can try using `phpstorm/php-apache:latest` instead just as a test, but otherwise, contacting support (Help | Contact Support) seems to be the only way to go here.

Comment: I'm fairly certain IntelliJ is starting a brand new container and scanning that, and not the container currently running that has the configuration changes (I did them by hand, band practice I know).

Comment: Oh. Sure thing it is. It wouldn't be able to attach the phpinfo volume to the container otherwise.
You are using `exec` mode? If so, you can ignore this message and just debug your code ignoring it. Or, you can configure the image in such a way that it had everythint configured right from the start.